# Android - Error when inflating custom View in XML

Tags: java, android, android-inflate

I have a custom view but I'm unable to use it because something related to namespaces that causing an Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.pc.easycalc, PID: 30694
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pc.easycalc/com.example.pc.easycalc.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class MyDisplay

...
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class MyDisplay
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class MyDisplay
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.MyDisplay" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.pc.easycalc-1/base.apk",
```

My custom view:

```
package com.example.pc.easycalc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyDisplay extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    public MyDisplay(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // ..
    }

    public MyDisplay(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // ..
    }

    public MyDisplay(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // ..
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // here
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pc.easycalc.MainActivity">


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml (where my custom view is used)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/display"
        style="DisplayContainer"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hotDisplay"
            android:textColor="@color/quasiWhite"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="12 +"
            style="@style/DisplayStyle"
            />

        <MyDisplay
            android:id="@+id/resDisplay"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:text="0.0000000"
            style="@style/DisplayStyle"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    ...
```

Thank you in advance!

PD: There is a couple of threads about this but I could not solve my problem with a custom view.

Comment: What is the package of your class MyDisplay ?

Comment: Hi @Jorgesys. The namespace for MyDisplay is the same of the MainActivity where is inflated:  package com.example.pc.easycalc;   -- thanks

Comment: OK just define the complete package to your view  <com.example.pc.easycalc.MyDisplay @boctulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the fully-qualified name of your view.  Use `<com.example.pc.easycalc.MyDisplay>` in your layout xml.  When a fully qualified name is not specified, the `LayoutInflater` defaults to searching in `android.widget` and `android.view`, and your view does not exist in those packages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is defined as:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.MyDisplay"

you are declaring the view in your layout:

```
  <MyDisplay
        android:id="@+id/resDisplay"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:text="0.0000000"
        style="@style/DisplayStyle"
        />
```

but  you have to set the complete package ( fully-qualified name ), i think that must be :

```
 <com.example.pc.easycalc.MyDisplay
        android:id="@+id/resDisplay"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:text="0.0000000"
        style="@style/DisplayStyle"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it using :

```
<com.example.pc.easycalc.MyDisplay
        android:id="@+id/resDisplay"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:text="0.0000000"
        style="@style/DisplayStyle"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

It will give you an exception because except Google Library views no one can create a view that won't show the package name front of layout name:

> So add the package name of your class front of layout name...

---

> com. ___ .MyDisplay

Comment: Thanks @"Tarlan Ahad" but I've already tried using:   com.example.pc.easycalc.MyDisplay with the *same* result.